# Fragment not attached to Activity while loading adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-room

I'm having this error while im loading the Fragment for a second time. This is very strange because on the first time the fragment load wihout any problem. Here is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ShopFragment{8f5d575} (89cc4724-c435-49f4-ad05-4de4f1d18fc9)} not attached to an activity.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
    at com.example.fragmentapp.ui.fragments.ShopFragment$4.onChanged(ShopFragment.java:138)
```

This happens only when i open the fragment for a second time, and the app crashes. I'm starting with MVVM and Room so im not an expert on the matter so im i little lost.
Here is the code from my fragment

```
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {

private ShopViewModel shopViewModel;

private Spinner spDeptoShop;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    shopViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShopViewModel.class);


    spDeptoShop = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sp_deparmento_shop);


    init();

    subscribeObservers();

}

private void init() {
    shopViewModel.getDeptosLocal();
}


private void subscribeObservers() {
    shopViewModel.getDeptos().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<Resource<List<Departamento>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Resource<List<Departamento>> listResource) {
            if(listResource != null){
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: status: " + listResource.status);
                if(listResource.data != null){
                    switch (listResource.status){
                        case LOADING:{
                            break;
                        }
                        case ERROR:{
                            Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: cannot refresh the cache." );
                            Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: ERROR message: " + listResource.message );
                            Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: status: ERROR, #DEPARTAMENTO: " + listResource.data.size());
                            break;
                        }
                        case SUCCESS:{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: cache has been refreshed.");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: status: SUCCESS, #DEPARTAMENTO: " + listResource.data.size());
                            if(listResource.data != null && listResource.data.size()>0)
                            {
                                spDeptoShop.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<Departamento>(requireActivity(), R.layout.spinner_list_item, listResource.data));
                            }
                            else{

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    shopViewModel.cancelRequest();
}
```

}

The error is in the line:

```
                        spDeptoShop.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<Departamento>(requireActivity(), R.layout.spinner_list_item, listResource.data));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `observe()` with `requireActivity()` - your Activity's Lifecycle. That means you will continue to receive results until your Activity is stopped - i.e., it isn't tied to your Fragment's lifecycle at all, meaning it will continue to receive results even after your fragment is detached. You should never use `requireActivity()` with `observe()` in a Fragment.

Fragments have a special lifecycle specifically tied to when their views are created - [`getViewLifecycleOwner()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner()). This is what you should be using for your `observe`:

```
shopViewModel.getDeptos().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Resource<List<Departamento>>>() {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was unaware of this. Now works perfectly.